# GeoDjango distance filter with distance value stored within model - query

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have an `Order` model, that has an `origin` PointField and a `range` IntegerField. Furthermore, there is an `UserProfile` model, which has a `geo_location` PointField. Now, I have an `User` instance, `user`. I want to select all `Orders`, whose distance between `Order.origin` and `user.userprofile.geo_location` is less then the value (meters) in the `Order.range` model field.

So again, simplified models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    origin = models.PointField()
    range = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=10000)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    geo_location = models.PointField()
```

I've got this working (passing the distance statically):

```
>>> Order.objects.filter(origin__distance_lte=(user.profile.geo_location, D(m=3000)))
```

My next (unsuccessful) try was to use an [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions) expression to use the value from the `Order.range` field:

```
>>> Order.objects.filter(origin__distance_lte=(user.profile.geo_location, D(m=F('range'))))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/measure.py", line 165, in __init__
self.m, self._default_unit = self.default_units(kwargs)
  File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/measure.py", line 49, in default_units
if not isinstance(value, float): value = float(value)
 TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I think the problem is that the D() isn't ran lazily - I can understand that.
So I tried to just take the raw value from the `range` field (integer) which I supposed to work, but:

```
>>> Order.objects.filter(origin__distance_lte=(user.profile.geo_location, F('range')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 69, in __repr__
data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 84, in __len__
self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 273, in iterator
for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 680, in results_iter
for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 725, in execute_sql
sql, params = self.as_sql()
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 68, in as_sql
where, w_params = self.query.where.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=self.connection)
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 92, in as_sql
sql, params = child.as_sql(qn=qn, connection=connection)
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py", line 95, in as_sql
sql, params = self.make_atom(child, qn, connection)
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/sql/where.py", line 47, in make_atom
spatial_sql = connection.ops.spatial_lookup_sql(data, lookup_type, params_or_value, lvalue.field, qn)
File "/Users/danger/devel/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py", line 531, in spatial_lookup_sql
raise ValueError('Argument type should be %s, got %s instead.' % (arg_type, type(value[1])))
ValueError: Argument type should be (<class 'decimal.Decimal'>, <class 'django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance'>, <type 'float'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'long'>), got <class 'django.db.models.expressions.F'> instead.
```

So how can I accomplish what I am trying to? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I think you're going to have to drop some SQL in to do what you want, as the GeoDjango helpers don't have a way of you making a suitable `Distance` object that is simultaneously a Django `F` object (ie field lookup). You don't say which database you're using, but here's how you do it with PostGIS:

```
Order.objects.all().extra(
    where=['ST_Distance(origin, ST_PointFromText(%s, 4326)) <= CAST(range AS double precision) / 1000'],
    params=[user.profile.geo_location.wkt]
)
```

Let's explain what's happening here, because it's pretty thorny. Going from the left:

- `.extra()` allows you to add extra fields and restrictions into a query; here we're adding a restriction
- [`ST_Distance()`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html#id2574517) is the PostGIS function that the GeoDjango `distance_lte` operator converts into (from [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-distance_lte))
- [`ST_PointFromText()`](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html#id2575932) converts from WKT syntax into a PostGIS Geometry object
- `4326` is [the default SRID for Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#srid), but not for PostGIS so we have to specify it
- we have to [`CAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) your field to double precision because you're using an integer
- then we have to divide by 1000 to convert from metres into kilometres, which I *believe* is what we need
- GeoDjango `Point` fields have an accessor `.wkt` which gives their WKT representation, which we needed earlier in our `ST_PointFromText()` call

Note that according to the PostGIS documentation, `ST_Distance()` doesn't use indexes, so you may want to investigate using `ST_DWithin()` instead (it's documented right after `ST_Distance()`).

Comment: Thanks for your effort putting this answer together. In the end I ended up with a solution described here: http://blog.adamfast.com/2011/11/radius-limited-searching-with-the-orm/

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. But, I found ST_Distance() to be returning lon/lat degrees instead of meters. Here's what I did to get meters:

providers = providers.extra(
            where=['ST_Distance(ST_Transform(origin, 2163), ST_Transform(ST_PointFromText(%s, 4326), 2163)) <= range'],
            params=[user.profile.geo_location.wkt]
        )

SRID 2163 is a conical projection of the united states.  I found casting to double unnecessary too.

Comment: I believe `ST_Distance()` works differently depending on if you give it `Geometry` objects or `Geography`. (This may or may not have changed since my original answer.)

Comment: What a life saver