# Object has no attribute 'distance' - GeoDjango

Tags: django, django-queryset, geodjango, geopy

I am referring to the answer in the question listed below as I am trying to run a query that gets the closest object to a given point in my django application. My django version is 1.9.2.

[How to return a record with the lowest distance from a point using geodjango?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557182/how-to-return-a-record-with-the-lowest-distance-from-a-point-using-geodjango)

In my view I am passing in a Zipcode and using GeoPy to get the location and lat/long.

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import *
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim()

zipcode = self.request.query_params.get('zipcode', None)
distance_m = 20000

if zipcode is not None:
    location = geolocator.geocode(zipcode, timeout=None)
    origin = Point((location.latitude, location.longitude))

    queryset = Chapter.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(origin, D(m=distance_m))).distance(origin).order_by('distance')[:1][0] 
    return queryset
```

The **Chapter** model has a field called **location** which is a point field.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    verification = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address1 = models.TextField()
    address2 = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.TextField()
    state = models.TextField()
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True)
    is_school = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_association = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    authorized = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
    stripe_account_active = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_nickname(self):
        return self.school.nickname
```

I get the following error when this executes:

```
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'distance'
```

**Edit--**

When I try to get the distance using the alternate method in the questions above I get a different error which makes me think there is something wrong with my model.

```
point = Chapter.objects.get(name='Chapter of the Year').location
distance_m = 20000

for chapter in Chapter.objects.distance(point):
    print(chapter.name, chapter.distance)
```

Error:

```
'Manager' object has no attribute 'distance'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in this line :

```
queryset = Chapter.objects.filter(location__distance_lte = (origin, D(m=distance_m))).distance(origin).order_by('distance')[:1][0]
```

You are ordering the result by **distance** but that is not a field/attribute in Chapter model. 
I think what you want is order by **location__distance**, so the actual filter query should be:

```
queryset = Chapter.objects.filter(location__distance_lte= (origin, D(m=distance_m))).distance(origin).order_by('location__distance')[:1][0]
```

Also this line is totally incorrect :

```
for chapter in Chapter.objects.distance(point):
```

Because here, **distance** is not a method like **filter** or **get**.
It should be something like that :

```
point = Chapter.objects.get(name='Chapter of the Year')
distance_m = 20000

for chapter in Chapter.objects.filter(id = point.id ):
    print(chapter.name, chapter.location.distance)
```

Comment: I just tried this and its still not working. I just added some additional context to the question after trying to loop through and get the distance for each instance.

Comment: @BrandonMitchell The problem with both conditions are the same. **Chapter** model does not have a field/ attribute named **distance**.

Comment: @BrandonMitchell Please add the code of model **Chapter** also in the question. That will help in solving the problem.

Comment: @BrandonMitchell You can notice from the question from where you are taking help, that answer does not mention anything about this method. It was Op's mistake in that question also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143564/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-brandon-mitchell).

Comment: Still trying to get the queryset to return the closest location.

Answer (score 6):

Got this to work

```
Chapter.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(origin, D(m=distance_m))).annotate(distance=Distance('location', origin)).order_by('distance')[:1][0]
```

Comment: From where did you import `Distance`?

Comment: @BrettJackson `from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance`