# Django filter location distance with dynamic radius

Tags: python, django, orm, geodjango

I have 2 model in django a zone and a shop, models are like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from location_field.models.spatial import LocationField


class Zone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location_point = LocationField(based_fields=['city'], zoom=7, default=Point(51.67, 32.65))
    radius = models.IntegerField(default=1000)  # radius in meters

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location_point = LocationField(based_fields=['city'], zoom=7, default=Point(51.67, 32.65), null=True, blank=True)
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

[LocationField](https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field) is a PointField with a better map in django admin.

I want on every shop saving select zone automatically base on shop location , zone location and radius. If there is no zone with radius to support shop it will be None. I tried this query:

```
zone_list = Zone.objects.filter(
    location_point__distance_lte=(
        shop.location_point, D(m=models.F('radius'))
    )
)
```

But I get this error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'F'

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the value of `models.F('radius')` in this context?

Comment: @jchung it will get column radius from current row (in this query zone radius)  it must be integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to happen inside the `MeasureBase` class of `django.contrib.gis.measure` (which [`Distance`/`D`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/measure/#django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance) inherits from) and more specifically [in the `default_units` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/measure.py#L172) where it tries to cast `str` or numeric input values to `float` but receives an `F` expression instead.

What we can do as a workaround, is to `annotate` the [`Distance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#distance) (***careful with this `Distance` method because it comes from the GeoDjango Geographic Database Functions***) between the `shop.location_point` and the current `location_point` and then we can filter by that distance being `<=` than the instance `radius`:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

zone_list = Zone.objects.annotate(
    distance=Distance('location_point', shop.location_point)
).filter(distance__lte=F('radius'))
```

Kudos to this excellent answer from @e4c5: [GeoDjango filter by distance from a model field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609729/geodjango-filter-by-distance-from-a-model-field)

Another approach would be to eliminate the `annotation` part entirely and go straight to the filtering by `Distance`:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance

zone_list = Zone.objects.filter(
    radius_gte=Distance('location_point', shop.location_point)
)
```

---

*I leave this here for comment continuity:*

<s>You can try to cast the `F('radius')` result as a `FloatField()` using the [`Cast()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) method to turn the Integer to a Float.</s>

```
zone_list = Zone.objects.filter(
    location_point__distance_lte=(
        shop.location_point, 
        D(m=Cast('radius', output_field=models.FloatField()))
    )
)
```

Comment: I checked your answer but it didn't worked! TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Cast'.

Comment: @Mastisa I hadn't tested that, my bad. Is it possibe that some of you `radius` is set to `None` and not as an integer?

Comment: No it always have an integer. I think problem is with D method, it work with an int like 1000 but didn't accept methods. is it related?

Comment: @Mastisa Maybe. Can you try the following: `D(m=models.F('radius')*Decimal(1.0))` and let me know what happens?

Comment: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'CombinedExpression'

Comment: @Mastisa I have edited the answer with a workaround. Have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had a solution like this but definitely your solution is better than mine. I think the real answer for this question is a way to convert argument of D method to float.

Comment: @Mastisa I researched the problem a bit and I didn't find a way to convert the `D` to float. But I composed a more straightforward way to filter without the extra step of the annotation, which I added to the answer.